# QML TextInput: how detect focus out event?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I need analog of https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#editingFinished-signal .
So when user press enter/space, change focus to anther item I need signal.
The problem is that editingFinished is useless for me. It works only if
there are no mask/validator, in other case if `TextInput` is invalid/incomplete state,
there are no editingFinished signal. So I want it emulation.
I can not inherit `QQuickTextInput` in C++ because of it is private class.
I can inherit `TextInput` in QML, but how can I get `focusOutEvent` inside QML class
that inherit `TextInput`?

Comment: Does `onActiveFocusChanged` help?

Comment: @JarMan It works. I saw that QQuickItem has empty `focusOutEvent` and missed `activeFocusChange`

Comment: Great, then I'll write is as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use on the `activeFocus` property to check whether an object has focus or not.

```
TextInput {
    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        if (activeFocus) {
            // Gained focus
        } else {
            // Lost focus
        }
    }
}
```